# Is it possible to join the Server Fault community using my Stack Exchange login?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, community, serverfault

Aside from Server Fault, when I visit ( seemingly ) any of the other [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) where I am not already active, I am presented with the option to **Join** followed by an option to sign in using my Stack Exchange community login ( **Confirm and Create Account** ); however when I try the same for Server Fault I don't get this option — instead I get an option to sign in using Google or Facebook.

**Is it possible to join the Server Fault community using my Stack Exchange login?**

Comment: Looks like you already have an account there. I guess it was created using Google or Facebook: https://serverfault.com/users/134559/byronyasgur .

Comment: This could be because you are currently logged in with a google or facebook account. When I tried to make an account I was presented with the Create with Google Option as that is what I use to log in

Comment: Yes - that seems to be the case - I tried logging in with google and it worked straight away - I always avoid that on stack exchange so I never expected that ... sorry I should have tried it probably